# How to define slug based on other fieldName mongooseSchema

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

i have mongoose schema:

field 1: name:

```
        name: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        
    },
```

field 2 is the slug:

```
        slug: {     
        trim: true,
        type: String,
        index: true,
    },
```

- i have function that check if the name is validate with accept charcters:

  ```
   categorySchema.path("name").validate(function (name) {
   const regex = /^[0-9a-zא-ת- ]+$/;
   if (regex.test(name)) {
   return true;
   } else throw new Error("no accept");
   });
  ```

**what i want to do is:**
i try to define the slug based on the name that i get, and of course some manipulates to write the slug well,( like replace the spaces let slugFromName = name.split(" ").join("-");) .
and after to save it with the right content to the slugField.

**the problem:** I dont understand how to check the slug based on the nameField and save it

Answer (score 0):

you can validate the payload before it saving in mongoose. mongoose had a built in function for that.

```
name: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        validate: {
        validator: function (v) {
        return /^[0-9a-zא-ת- ]+$/.test(v);
      },
      message: (props) => `${props.value} is not accept!`
    }
}
```

before you need to manipulate the payload like so, example

```
var someFunction = (payload) => {
// here your manipulation
}
categorySchema({
name : payload.name,
slug : someFunction
}).save()
.then(docs => {
console.log(docs)
})
.catch(err){
throw err
}
```